# is there an excel formula to count rows in a table with a specific value?

Tags: excel-formula

I am using the rows() command to count the number of rows in a table but how would I count the number of rows in a table with a specific value e.g. the number of rows where the column Fruit contained the text Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`COUNTIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) function to do that, in the example below I use it to count the number of times the word "Apple" exists in the table column named "Fruit", in my example the formula ends up as:

```
=COUNTIF(Table1[Fruit];"Apple")
```

[image: Using the function COUNTIF to count rows with the word 'Apple']

Comment: needed to change the ; to a comma, but this worked.